# cmake INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES add only the 1st library

Tags: cmake

I think I have not understand something about **INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES** in cmake.
I have the following CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project("Tests")

add_library(external::lib01 STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(external::lib01 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "F:/Code/lib01/01.lib")

add_library(external::lib02 STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(external::lib02 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "F:/Code/lib02/02.lib")

add_library(externals INTERFACE)
set_target_properties(externals PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "F:/Code/include/")
set_target_properties(externals PROPERTIES INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES external::lib01 external::lib02)
#set_target_properties(externals PROPERTIES INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES external::lib01;external::lib02)

add_executable(test01 test01.cxx)
target_link_libraries(test01 externals)
```

After reading cmake's documentation (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES.html), my expectation was that test01 would be link with 01.lib and 02.lib, but the result is that test01 is linked **only** with lib01.
Why it does not behave as the documentation say : *When the target is linked into another target using the target_link_libraries() command, the libraries listed (and recursively their link interface libraries) will be provided to the other target also.*

Any help in understanding this issue will be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Answer to "why does `set_target_properties` work this way?" aside, would you be open to changing to `target_link_libraries(externals INTERFACE external::lib01 external::lib02)` instead? Which is the more canonical way to add interface libraries.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is a working solution, that i will use. Just a little sad, it does not help me to understand what I missed in the cmake documentation.

Comment: Thank you to the people that closed my question and linked it to a question that has nothing to do with it. It is very usefull, thank you.

Comment: the linked question very clearly explains how `set_target_properties` sets multiple properties, and if you want a single property to have multiple values (such as a list) a few workarounds. The linked question is unsarcastically helpful.